# Database Records in 3 div columns with php

Tags: php, html

I have product list ( 9 products in multidimensional array ), i want to achieve that all 9 product will be ordered in 3 div columns.
for example

```
 product1       product4       product7
 product2       product5       product8
 product3       product6       product9
```

And my array structure is

```
array(
  array(product_name1),
  array(product_name2),
  array(product_name3),
  array(produ‌​ct_name4),
  array(product_name5)
)
```

i have html code how this must look like

```
<div class="container">
<div class="prod-column">
    <div class="product-slot">
        product1
    </div>
    <div class="product-slot">
        product2
    </div>
    <div class="product-slot">
        product3
    </div>
</div> <!-- close column -->
<div class="prod-column">
    <div class="product-slot">
        product4
    </div>
    <div class="product-slot">
        product5
    </div>
    <div class="product-slot">
        product6
    </div>
</div> <!-- close column -->
<div class="prod-column">
    <div class="product-slot">
        product7
    </div>
    <div class="product-slot">
        product8
    </div>
    <div class="product-slot">
        product9
    </div>
</div> <!-- close column -->
</div> <!-- close container -->
```

Also i find code on [Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505788/php-tricky-array-into-columns-but-in-a-specific-order)

but in my case i've got blank row at end, i can't find a reason why i've got this empty prod-column at end

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: array(array(product_name1),array(product_name2),array(product_name3),array(product_name4),array(product_name5))

Comment: also i check linked code with 8 products and then this code work, it also work if i put 10 products

Comment: duplicate of [How to create php 2 column table with values from the database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299913/how-to-create-php-2-column-table-with-values-from-the-database) and many many many more

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. Assumes your product name is the first element of an indexed array - if it isn't, modify `$array[$i][0]` appropriately. Also assumes you have a number of products divisible by three (which presumably wont always be the case) so it doesn't generate empty filler fields, but hopefully it will give you the idea.

```
echo "<div class=\"container\">\n";

for ($i = 0, $j = 0; isset($array[$i]); $i++) {
  if ($j == 0) {
    echo "<div class=\"prod-column\">\n";
  }
  echo "    <div class=\"product-slot\">\n        {$array[$i][0]}\n    </div>\n";
  if ($j == 2) {
    echo "</div>\n";
    $j = 0;
  } else $j++;
}

echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Seriously, I don't mind being wrong/being disagreed with, but downvoting with no explanation is just rude, and does not promote people learning from their mistakes...

Comment: i didn't give any vote for you since i still checking your first version of code

Comment: No worries, not having a go at you, just the floating-downvoters out there. Like I say, this may not produce the result you expect if you have, say, 8 results instead of 9. You should try this code with a number of results not divisible by 3 to make sure you are still happy with the way it displays.

Answer (score 0):

Ms solution would be  like this:

```
<div class="container">
<?php
for ($i = 0,$c=count($array); $i<$c; $i++) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
?>
<div class="prod-column">
<?php
    }
?>
<div class="product-slot"><?php echo $array[$i][product];?></div>
<?php
    if ($i % 3 == 2) {
?>
</div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</div>
```